# How to get the title or another attribute of an Image in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I am building a custom shirt builder for a website http://mytempsite.net/gotie/mixandmatch

What I have setup is step one, they will select a shirt color from 12 different shirts and then move on to the next step where they will be able to choose a tie. I need to be able to pass a variable to that next page telling it to only pull images with ties on it for example the red shirt.

My thought of doing this is by having that attribute at the image alt or title tag and then getting that attribute from the current image that is being displayed.

What i need to know is how?

i tried using this code as a start

```
<?php
    $url=$this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();;

    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);

    $divs = $doc->getElementByID('loadarea');

    foreach ($divs as $div) {
           echo "Found the loadarea div <br />";
    }
?>
```

but it didn't work, and it also caused my page to load really slowly.

just in case here is code to thumbnails

```
<?php 
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    foreach($products as $prod) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());
        $pro_title = $product->getName();
        $img = $product->getImageUrl();

        echo "<a href='".$img."' title='".$pro_title."' rel='enlargeimage' rev='targetdiv:loadarea,enabletitle:no,trigger:click,preload:none,fx:fade'><img src='".$img."' width='100px'/></a>";

}?>
```

I hope that i worded this question correctly as to not be too localized. If so i will reword it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing is when the thumbnail image gets clicked a hidden text box gets the product_id of that shirt and then when you go to the next page it automatically pulls the product image of that product. I have inserted the code for my entire form incase anyone ever needs to do this in the future :)

Happy Coding!

```
         <form id="GoTie_Builder" method="POST" action="/gotie/mixandmatch/tie">
                                <script>
                                function changeInput(pro_id)
                                {
                                    var my_form = document.getElementById('GoTie_Builder');
                                    my_form.shirt_color.value = pro_id;
                                }

                                function changePattern(pattern)
                                {
                                    var my_div = document.getElementById('shirt_zoom');
                                    my_div.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.tuxedojunction.com/Content/Products/Vests/LegacyBlueVelvet_s_1.jpg" />';

                                }

                                </script>
                                <div id="shirt_zoom" style="width:300px; height:100px;">
                                <img src="http://www.tuxedojunction.com/Content/Products/Vests/LegacyBlueVelvet_s_1.jpg" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="Builder_thumbnails" style="float:left;">

                            <?php 
                                $cat_id = 8;
                                $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)->getProductCollection();
                                echo '<input id="shirt_color" type="text" name="shirt_color" value="0">';
                                foreach($products as $prod) {
                                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());

                                    $pattern = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');

                                    //echo "<img onclick='changeInput($pro_id)' class='product_thumbnail' src='".$pattern."' alt='".$pro_id."' width='100px'/>";


                                    $pro_id = $product->getId();
                                    $pro_title = $product->getName();
                                    $img = $product->getImageUrl();


                                    $input_id = "shirt_color";
                                    echo "<a href='".$img."' title='".$pro_title."' rel='enlargeimage' rev='targetdiv:loadarea,enabletitle:no,trigger:click,preload:none,fx:fade'><img onclick='changeInput($pro_id)' class='product_thumbnail' src='".$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')."' alt='".$pro_id."' width='100px' height='100px'/></a>";

         }?>

  </div>      


         <div id="loadarea" style="width:300px;top: 0px;right: 0px;float: right;position: relative;"><img src="http://cdn4.blackenterprise.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2011/07/White-Shirt-620x480.jpg" width="500px;"/>

         </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Choose a Tie" />
         </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>I believe $someVar = get_field('image file') should return an array of all the tagged data in the image.  You can then access the data from the array (ie. $someVar['alt']).</del>

Here is a simpler solution that doesn't require you make the image into an object.

```
$html=file_get_contents("URL OF YOUR SITE");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc -> loadHTML($html);
    // Add a class to your big image to identify it (ex. selected)
$tags = getElementsByClassName($doc, 'selected');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('alt');
}


    // Not my function but its very useful.  I'll track down where I got it
    // and add source later.    
function getElementsByClassName(DOMDocument $DOMDocument, $ClassName) {
    $Elements = $DOMDocument -> getElementsByTagName("*");
    $Matched = array();

    foreach($Elements as $node)
    {
        if( ! $node -> hasAttributes())
            continue;

        $classAttribute = $node -> attributes -> getNamedItem('class');

        if( ! $classAttribute)
                continue;

        $classes = explode(' ', $classAttribute -> nodeValue);

        if(in_array($ClassName, $classes))
            $Matched[] = $node;
    }

    return $Matched;
}
```

Comment: But how would I do it to where it only gets the alt of the active big photo? Did you look at the site so you know what I am referring to?

Comment: yeah sorry, my bad.  I'll edit my original post with a simpler solution.

Comment: Will this automatically get updated each time the big image gets changed?

Comment: this was great and probably could of worked but I went a different route.  Will post answer shortly.